# Connection String Caching in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Web application. The application connects three different databases. So I have defined three connection string in web.config with different database name and credentials.From the application code I am pointing to the relevant connection string and firing stored procedures. Sometimes the procedures are hitting the wrong database. My guess is that as .NET cache the web.config, somehow the framework is returning the wrong connection string from cache and the application hitting the wrong database. I have checked the application code and found it is pointing to the correct connection database in all cases. Is this happening due to web.config chancing? I cannot identify the root cause of the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF to connect to the database, you have to close the scope of the context and then initialize a new context with the required connection string and then use that context to execute the SP.

I don't think this is an issue with the caching !

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one DAL which connecting to different databases then it is a high chance of application mistake somewhere.

Possible solution, as we have no idea of how is you data access code looks like, is to create 3 different DAL and in each of them realize logic to work only with specified connection string.

For example create 3 different classes inherited from DbContext with different connection strings in constructors.